# Configuring dynamic URL rewrite policies

Tags: citrix, netscaler

I want to add a rewrite policy in Citrix netscaler.
/activities/* should go to one server
/activities/*/* should go to another server

So what are the content policies I need to configure in url rewrite of netscaler?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about URL rewrite, it will be a payne. Take a look at the URL Transformation feature on the NetScaler https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/netscaler/12/appexpert/rewrite/url-transformation/configure-rewrite-proxy-requests.html

Note: After you make this work you might need to create additional policies to correct hardcoded links and other things on the source code of your website. **It might take quite an effort**. good luck